# :even & :odd - resetting after each sub heading

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I have this table:

```
<style>

    table thead tr { background-color: #D5D5D5 ; font-size:9pt}
    table tr.asmtHeader { background-color: #E3E3E3; }
    table tr.dataRow td { text-align: center; vertical-align: top; }
    table tr.dataRow:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #EFEFEF; }

</style>

<table>                
    <thead><tr><th></tr></thead>        
    <tr class="asmtHeader"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="dataRow"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="dataRow"><td>should be #EFEFEF</td></tr>
        <tr class="dataRow"><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="asmtHeader"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="dataRow"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="dataRow"><td>should be #EFEFEF</td></tr>
        <tr class="dataRow"><td></td></tr>
        <tr class="dataRow"><td>should be #EFEFEF</td></tr>         
</table>
```

The goal is to zebra stripe just the class="dataRow", but always start off with clear on the first one after the class="asmtHeader". If I remove the 'table tr.dataRow:nth-child(odd)' styling and add this line, it will exclude the asmtHeader, but does not reset the even/odd:

```
$("tr.dataRow:odd").css( {
    "background": "#EFEFEF", 
    "text-align": "center", 
    "vertical-align": "top" });
```

Is there a way to get the even/odd to reset?

Comment: unfortunately nth-child is an element selector.  Given that you seem to have a header row repeating through your table, shouldn't the part below the header (and including the header row) be in their own table to make it more semantically correct?

Comment: Pete,  I saw something about putting each subsection into a <tbody> which is what I am working on now.  It is my understanding that you cannot have a <thead> after a <tbody>.

Comment: Why do you need jQuery for this styling, out of curiosity? It can and already is being done in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see asmtHeader should be a table header so why don't make it th.You can complicate with jquery searching for first `asmtHeader` that can find and then give separate classes on next tr and then search again for next `asmtHeader`(a loop so) but this solution use css and js and is complicated.

Based on this question https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25941/trouble-zebra-striping-a-table-with-children-with-css
you can use

```
            <tr><th>Parent 1</th></tr>
            <tr><td>Child A</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Child B</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Child C</td></tr>
```

structure.You can find the example from that topic here http://jsfiddle.net/3MH9h/